# how i can send plu to barcode ACLASS & Roginta scale using c#

Tags: c#, scale

i Have many types of barcode scales so i want to send items data by my POS program But when i searched more i knew that i should use this PBusDrv.dll   and follow the documentation below after i tried every thing i knew i got PBusTransferPLUCluster function not working giving me {The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))}
so is any one can help me solving this issue  ??

this is the code

```
   //
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TPlu ONEPLU;


        [DllImport("PBusDrv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

        private static extern int PBusConnect(string RefLFZKFileName, string RefCFGFileName, string SerialNO, string CommName, int BaudRate);
        [DllImport("PBusDrv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int PBusConnectEx(string RefLFZKFileName, string RefCFGFileName, string IPAddr);

        [DllImport("PBusDrv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int PBusDisConnect(string SerialNO);

        [DllImport("PBusDrv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int PBusTransferPLUCluster(ref PPLUCluster PPC);
        public struct TPLUCluster
        {
            public TPlu[] PLU;

        }
        public struct PPLUCluster
        {
            public TPLUCluster[] TPLUCluster;

        }
        public struct TPlu
        {
            //    TPlu=record           //PLU data structure
            public string Name;  //product name, 36 characters
            public int LFCode; //Lfcode,1-999999,only way to identify each kind of product 
            public int Hotkey;
            public string Code;  //product code，10 digit, used to form barcode
            public int BarCode;    //barcode type,0-99
            public int UnitPrice;    //unit price, did not have decimal mode, 0-9999999
            public int WeightUnit;    //weight unit 0-12
            public int Deptment; //department,2 number, used to form barcode 
            public double Tare;  //tare weight, it should within 15Kg after logic conversion 
            public int ShlefTime;  //shelf time,0-365
            public int PackageType;    //package type,0:normal/ limitative weight mode,1:weight fixed,2:price fixed,3:barcode printer mode
            public Double PackageWeight;    //package weight/limitative weight, it should within 15Kg after logic conversion
            public int Tolerance;  //package error tolerance,0-20
            public byte Message1;   //message 1,0-197
            public byte Reserved;   //reserved
            public string Reserved1;    //reserved
            public byte Message2;   //message 2,0-197
            public byte Reserved2;  //reserved
            public byte MultiLabel; //multi-label,0-255,8 Bit corresponding to A0-D1 respectively
            public short Rebate;  //rebate,0-99
            public int Account; //enter an item in an account, reserved
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Int64 aa = 1;
                string IP = "192.168.1.87"; //lfzkfull.DAT
                aa = PBusDisConnect(IP);
                aa = PBusConnectEx("C:\\Users\\Royal\\source\\repos\\WindowsFormsApp1\\WindowsFormsApp1\\bin\\Debug\\lfzk.DAT", "C:\\Users\\Royal\\source\\repos\\WindowsFormsApp1\\WindowsFormsApp1\\bin\\Debug\\SYSTEM.CFG", IP);

                ONEPLU.Name = "TahaYOU";
                ONEPLU.LFCode = 2;
                ONEPLU.Code = "10001";// IP;
                ONEPLU.BarCode = 7;
                ONEPLU.UnitPrice = 60000;
                ONEPLU.WeightUnit = 4;
                ONEPLU.Deptment = 21;
                ONEPLU.Tare = 0;
                ONEPLU.ShlefTime = 15;
                ONEPLU.PackageType = 0;
                ONEPLU.PackageWeight = 0;
                ONEPLU.Tolerance = 5;
                ONEPLU.Reserved = 0;
                ONEPLU.Reserved1 = "";
                ONEPLU.Message1 = 0;
                ONEPLU.Message2 = 0;
                ONEPLU.MultiLabel = 0;
                ONEPLU.Rebate = 0;
                ONEPLU.Account = 0;
                ONEPLU.Hotkey = 2;



                TPLUCluster TPLUCluster = new TPLUCluster();
                TPLUCluster.PLU = new TPlu[4];
                TPLUCluster.PLU[0] = ONEPLU;
                ONEPLU.Hotkey = 3;
                ONEPLU.LFCode = 3;
                TPLUCluster.PLU[1] = ONEPLU;
                ONEPLU.Hotkey = 4;
                ONEPLU.LFCode = 4;
                TPLUCluster.PLU[2] = ONEPLU;
                ONEPLU.Hotkey = 5;
                ONEPLU.LFCode = 5;
                TPLUCluster.PLU[3] = ONEPLU;

                TPLUCluster[] TPLUClusterA = new TPLUCluster[1];
                TPLUClusterA = new TPLUCluster[1];
                TPLUClusterA[0] = TPLUCluster;


                PPLUCluster ppc = new PPLUCluster();
                ppc.TPLUCluster = TPLUClusterA;
                aa = PBusTransferPLUCluster(ref ppc);
                aa = PBusDisConnect(IP);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the documentation

```
PBusDrv.DLL use explanation 

PBusDrv.DLL is a 32 digit dynamic link libraries, mostly is used to download PLU data to Pinncale label scale. 
Main Data structure and function: (Delphi syntax. For other languages, please refer to use):

1.Data structure
TPlu=record         //PLU data structure
     Name:         PChar;   //product name, 36 characters
     LFCode:       Longint; //Lfcode,1-999999,only way to identify each kind of product 
     Code:         PChar;   //product code，10 digit, used to form barcode
     BarCode:      Longint; //barcode type,0-99
     UnitPrice:    Longint; //unit price, did not have decimal mode, 0-9999999
     WeightUnit:   Longint; //weight unit 0-12
     Deptment:     Longint; //department,2 number, used to form barcode 
     Tare:         Double;  //tare weight, it should within 15Kg after logic conversion 
     ShlefTime:    Longint; //shelf time,0-365
     PackageType:  Longint; //package type,0:normal/ limitative weight mode,1:weight fixed,
                             //2:price fixed,3:barcode printer mode
     PackageWeight:Double;  //package weight/limitative weight, it should within 15Kg after logic conversion
     Tolerance:    Longint; //package error tolerance,0-20
     Message1:     Byte;    //message 1,0-197
     Reserved:     Byte;    //reserved
     Reserved1:    Word;    //reserved
     Message2:     Byte;    //message 2,0-197
     Reserved2:    Byte;    //reserved
     MultiLabel:   Byte;    //multi-label,0-255,8 Bit corresponding to A0-D1 respectively
     Rebate:       ShortInt;    //rebate,0-99
     Account:      LongInt; //enter an item in an account, reserved
   end;
   PPLU=^TPLU;
   TPLUCluster=Array[0..3]of TPLU;  //one PLU cluster including 4 pcs PLU
   PPLUCluster=^TPLUCluster;
   THotkeyTable=Array[0..83]of LongInt; //each array element is a PLU lfcode,
                        //84 pcs element corresponding to 84 pcs PLU
   PHotkeyTable=^THotkeyTable;

   For detailed explanation, please refer to user manual’s program interface part.

2.Function(suppose label scale sw (LBMNC) is installed under XX directory)
Connect function
Function PBusConnect(RefLFZKFileName:PChar;//lf font list file name,including path,
                        //usually point to XX\bin\lfzk.dat
                                            //if used character set，point to XX\bin\lfzkfull.dat
RefCFGFileName:PChar;   //configuration file name, including path, usually point to //XX\bin\system.cfg
SerialNO:DWord;     //label scale serial number, if is Ethernet, please transfer IP address as
//DWord，such as 192.168.0.1 transfer to $C0A80001
                     CommName:PChar;        //equipment name, such as:COM1,COM2，if is Ethernet, it is:IP
                     BaudRate:Integer   //communication speed, set as 0
                     ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

Function PBusConnectEx(RefLFZKFileName:PChar;// lf font list file name, including path,
                        //usually point to XX\bin\lfzk.dat
                                            //if use character set，point to XX\bin\lfzkfull.dat
RefCFGFileName:PChar;   //configuration file name, including path, usually point to //XX\bin\system.cfg
                     IPAddr: PChar;     //label scale IP address, such as:192.168.0.1
                     ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

Disconnect function
Function PBusDisConnect(SerialNO: DWord //label scale serial no.
                        ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

Function PBusDisConnectEx(IPAddr: PChar;    //label scale IP address，such as:192.168.0.1
                        ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

send PLU function
Function PBusTransferPLUCluster(PPC:PPLUCluster //PLU cluster
                                ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

send Hotkey function
Function PBusTransferHotkey(HotkeyTable:PHotkeyTable; //hotkey list
                            TableIndex:Integer  //hotkey list no., total two list,0 and 1
                            ):Integer;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

send message function
Function PBusTransferMessage(Id:Integer; //info code，1~197
                               PMessage:PChar; //information text
                               DataLen:Integer //information text length
                               ):Integer;far; external 'PBusDrv.DLL';

transform PLU to character string
Function PBusPLUToStr(LPPLU:PPLU;       //PLU data
              LPStr:PChar       //character string(one line of TXP file), this finger must distribute space.
              ):Integer;Stdcall;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';

transform character string to PLU
Function PBusStrToPLU(LPStr:PChar;      //character string(one line to TXP file)
              LPPLU:PPLU        //PLU data
              ):Integer;Stdcall;far; external 'PbusDrv.dll';
clear all PLU
Function PBusClearPLUData:Integer;Stdcall;far; external 'PBusDrv.dll';

3.Flow
(1) PBusConnect if returned value<0, jump out
        |
(2) PBusTransferPLUCluster/PBusTransferHotkey   if returned value<0, jump to (4)
        |
(3) PBusTransferPLUCluster/PBusTransferHotkey   if returned value<0, jump to (4)
        |
        .   if returned value<0, jump to (4)    
        .
        .
(4)     PBusDisConnect

4.Examples
  Example under Delphi60 catalog is writen with Delphi, could pass test under Delphi6.0.  Example under VB60 catalog is written with Visual Basic, could pass test under VB6.0.
  Example under VC60 catalog is written with Visual C++, could pass test under VC6.0.
  Example under PB65 catalog is written with PowerBuilder, could pass test under PB6.5.

Remarks：
1．Explanation of lf font bank and system parameter
PbusConnect connect function cites two file: lfzk.dat and system.cfg, lfzk.dat is lf font bank character list，store some system setting in system.cfg . We intensively suggest to cite corresponding file under link32 install catalog，to make sure that when Link32 sw modifying system parameter, it could reflect to dynamic link libraries in time。For example：There is a option “lf common font bank usage character set” of link32 system option，after modification of it， this parameter setting will be stored in system.cfg，if PbusConnect connect function cites system.cfg of link32 setting catalog ，the dynamic link libraries will download using new configure, or it will confuse the font bank. Of course, you could place these two file on other places, but must make sure update these two file in time and in-phase.
2．Setting of data align mode of delphi 6 and Delphi 7.
Set delphi6 and delphi7 as below,
Project->Options->Code generation->Record field alignment select 4
If do not want to change default setting (default value is 8) of Delphi data align mode or use Delphi5，could use PBusDrv.DLL of other catalog.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Consider adding some punctuations and code tags (``).  Also, it looks like you could remove irrelevant lines from your code. Making your question easy and fun to read is key to attract potential answerers.

Comment: My question is where is the mistake .

Comment: This code not working ,its just connect amd disconnect to scale but not sending data